# Why does Dummit and Foote seem to imply that $x^2+1$ and $2x^2+2$ do not have common zeros?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am reading Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, and in Chapter 13, Prop 9, the book says distinct irreducibles never have zeros in common. I think one irreducible can be got from another irreducible multiplied by a unit, such as in $\mathbb R[x]$, $x^2+1$ and $2x^2+2$ are both irreducibles but have common zeros. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Which edition of the text are you reading from?  In my edition of the text, Prop 13.9 (on page 520) reads "Let $\alpha$ be algebraic over $F$.  Then there is a unique **monic** irreducible polynomial $m_{\alpha, F}(x) \in F[x]$ which has $\alpha$ as a root.  A polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ has $\alpha$ as a root if and only if $m_{\alpha,F}(x)$ divides $f(x)$ in $F[x]$."

Comment: Assuming that you and I are working from the same edition of the text, it appears that this is simply a failure to read carefully enough.

Answer (score 3):

When talking divisibility, irreducibility, and similar, associate elements (i.e. one is a unit times the other) are usually considered non-distinct by convention.

Answer (score 3):

By distinct irreducibles, the author means upto a unit. Consider an equivalence class where $f \sim g$ if and only if $f=ug$ for some unit $u$. Under this equivalence class $f$ and $g$ are equal.

Answer (score 3):

Two irreducible with a common root would both be the minimal polynomial of that shared root and the minimal polynomial is unique up to multiplication by a constant factor.

Let $f,g\in F[x]$ be your two irreducible polynomials and suppose that in a field extension $F\hookrightarrow E$ they have a common root $\theta$, then $$I=\{p\in F[x]:p(\theta)=0\}\subseteq F[x]$$ is an ideal and is principal (since $F[x]$, for $F$ a field, is always a [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain)), that is $$I=(h)$$ for some polynomial $h$. Since $f(\theta)=g(\theta)=0$, there are $\alpha,\beta\in F[x]$ such that $$f=\alpha h,\qquad g=\beta h$$using that $f,g$ are irreducible, we conclude that $\alpha,\beta$ are both constants ($h$ cannot be a constant, as it would imply $(h)=I=F[x]$) and $$g=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}f$$

Comment: Thank you vary much!

Comment: If $h$ were a constant, then by definition it would have to be $0$, which is a contradiction since $f,g$ are non-zero and in $I$. (Your answer is good otherwise)

Comment: Yes @Evariste, you're right